# Match all links with empty anchor?

Tags: html, regex

What I am trying to do is to replace all anchor elements which have empty 'href' or their value is `#` with `button` element. In process if they have a class I want to add additional class  to it `btn btn-link` and keep all other attributes. I am trying to do this in Nodepad++.

this is my regex `<a (?=.*?href="#")(?:.*?class="(.*?)")?(.*?)>(.*)</a>`

```
<a href="#" data-ng-click="openDeleteDialog(futureTask,$event)" title="@ResourceDictionary.CommonDeleteLabel"><i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-lg"></i></a>

<a href="#" class="delete" data-ng-click="delete(futureTask,$event)"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></a>
```

convert to:

```
<button class="btn btn-link" data-ng-click="openDeleteDialog(futureTask,$event)" title="@ResourceDictionary.CommonDeleteLabel"><i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-lg"></i></button>

<button class="btn btn-link delete" data-ng-click="delete(futureTask,$event)"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></button>
```

Comment: Shouldn't `(.*)</a>` be non-greedy as well?

Comment: What language did you're running?

Comment: @AvinashRaj I need it to run in my IDE - Notepad++, VS ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to do this with 3 regular expression replaces.

1. **Convert *A* elements with** `href="#"` **to *BUTTON* elements:**
   Search string:   `<a\s+([^>]*?)href="#"([\s\S]+?)</a>`
   Replace string: `<button class="btn btn-link" \1\2</button>`
2. **Clean-up the whitespaces after** `class="btn btn-link"`**:**
   Search string:  `(class="btn btn-link")[\t ]{2,}`
   Replace string: `\1\x20`
3. **Join the classes within starting *BUTTON* tag:**
   Search string:  `(<button class="btn btn-link)"([^>]+?)class="(.+?)"\s*`
   Replace string: `\1 \3"\2`

It is of course possible to use a space character instead of `\x20` in second replace string.

Those 3 regular expression replaces were tested on several example lines with `href="#"` anywhere within starting *A* tag with new lines also present within *A* tag and string value using UltraEdit v21.20. Notepad++ should do the replaces identical to UltraEdit.